# How to change the meta key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've just started to put in the time to get to learn emacs. By default my meta key is bound to  Esc, and I'm finding that really inconvenient. I read somewhere however that it's not a good idea to change the binding to Alt. Is that true? If not, how could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's bound to Alt by default for me, and I have no problems with that. Are you on a Mac perhaps? There it is bound to one of the other keys like option.

If you are on a mac, the way to change the key will probably vary based on which version of Emacs you're using--e.g., I think changing it in the terminal would be different than changing it on one of the windowed varieties.

Another thing to try: http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/
Look through the keyboard layout with this and see if any key is assigned to `Meta`. If not, try assigning it; otherwise try changing it. I haven't actually tried this, but it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I'm actually using red hat.

Comment: Well, I've never used red hat, but I do know that on Solaris it maps to a key different from alt, which in this case has a diamond on it (weird Sun keyboards). Maybe try either the windows key or whatever you have in place of it works?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Mac, you can follow the directions from [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw445/CLWUG-M/html/clwuser-m-195.htm):

"If you do not want to use the Esc key, you can specify a key to use as Meta. To specify a Meta key, select the Emulation tab of the Editor Preferences dialog."

You can then select to use Alt or Command as your Meta key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I'm actually using red hat.

Comment: I think it will actually be the same settings.  Worth trying at least.

Answer (score 3):

For me, on my mac, it was bound to Alt by default, but I found it anoying because Alt is used for some special characters on Mac. 
I added these lines on my .emacs

```
(setq mac-function-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```

Thus in your case, you would have to add this in your .emacs (I tried this solution, and it worked for me)

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta) ; set alt-key to meta
(setq mac-escape-modifier nil) ; set esc-key to nil
```

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted you, your answer worked perfectly for me on my mac.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you're on Mac, because I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

1. Open Terminal
2. Open up the preferences
3. Open up the "Profiles" tab and choose the "Keyboard" tab with your current profile selected
4. Below the long scroll box are a couple check boxes. Check "Use Option as Meta key."

I'm using OS X 10.11.5, so I don't know about older versions of Terminal. I imagine that it would be similar.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution I've come across for Macs. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for emacs while remotely connected to my raspberry pi.

1. Go to terminal.
2. type:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Meta_L Alt_L"
   ```

This was suggested in xmodmap's manual

```
man xmodmap
```

Hope that helps :) I'm pretty new to this though so someone else may want to comment.

Comment: The OP asked for it to be done in Emacs. Using xmodmap would cause everything in that shell to be changed, not necessarily the desired outcome.